# Virtual Environment and Base Environment are Active at the Same Time

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, virtual-environment

I'm using Ubuntu Linux. I started the terminal and created a virtual environment as follows: python3 -m venv test. Then when I activated the test virtual environment by typing source test/bin/activate, in the prompt base environment was also showed as active. Why both base and virtual environment are active at the same time? How to solve this issue?

Prompt is like that: (test) (base) tkarahan@tkarahan:~$

Comment: Are you using a really old Python? Current versions certainly seem to `deactivate` the old env before going ahead to `activate` another.

Comment: No, it is Python 3.7.

Comment: Are you using any other tools for virtual environments?

Comment: Are you sure `(base)` is also the name of a virtual environment? How is your Bash prompt configured? Some configurations like to show e.g. the current Git branch in the prompt, too.

Comment: I only used venv.

Comment: I don't remember any configuration I made that might lead this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last environment you activate is active. It’s just an UI glitch caused by combining anaconda with some other environment manager. You can check which Python is on Your PATH with

```
which python
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems that test environment is active. The output is: /home/tkarahan/test/bin/python. So when I pip install, packages is only going to be installed in test environment because it is just an ui bug, right?

Comment: You can do ‚which pip‘. The packages will be installed in the folder ‚site-packages‘ in the same directory.

Comment: I did. It refers to the virtual environment's pip. It seems all okay, thank you.